# Как изменить символ на 1 (php)

Tags: php

Язык php.

```
$serial = "AA";
$serial[0] += 1;
```

Не работает так как php динамический, он просто присвоит $serial = 1, а мне нужна $serial = "BA", какие есть варианты? спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Может быть дело не в PHP?)

```
$serial = "AA";
$serial[0] = chr(ord($serial[0]) + 1);
echo $serial;
```

Comment: согласен, дела всегда в том кто пишет код...
я только смотрю возможности php.
Не выдержал и до этого нашел еще один способ)

    $letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $serial[0] =  $letters(ord($serial[0] - 64));
но твой вариант мне больше нравиться, кстати это я посмотрел с метода rot13(); интересно, почему они тоже так не сделали...